# GridView for Shopping Cart in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have made a simple shopping cart, I have completed it but the problem is when someone add an item to the cart it adds, and if that item again added to the cart then it add it as a new product, I need it to update the product if it already exists.
any help???
this code is written in page load of Cart View Page

```
DataTable dtCart = (DataTable)Session["sessiondtCart"];

            GridView1.DataSource = dtCart;
            GridView1.DataBind();    

            int total = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                total = total + int.Parse(dtCart.Rows[i]["PRODUCT_AMOUNT"].ToString());
            }
            lblTotalAmount.Text = total.ToString();
```

the code for adding items in the cart

```
protected void lnkBtnReadyToServeAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dtCart = (DataTable)Session["sessiondtCart"];
            dtCart.Rows.Add(lblProductName.Text, lblProductPrice.Text, txtQuantity.Text, imgk1.ImageUrl, int.Parse(lblProductPrice.Text) * int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text));
            Session["sessiondtCart"] = dtCart;

        }
```

Comment: You need to show your code for adding items to the cart. It sounds pretty straightforward. Prior to adding a new item, check if it's already in the cart, and update it if it is.

Comment: No, do not put it in a comment. It's not readable there, and it should have been part of your question to begin with. Please edit your question to include it, then remove your comment.

Comment: i have added my code in question

Comment: Okay, so now where's your attempt to check if the item is already in the `DataTable` prior to adding it? Give that a shot, it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: i have no idea how to do it, please help me with this

Comment: You seem to have no problem looping over the items in the first code block. So do that in `lnkBtnReadyToServeAdd_Click`, and find where the Product Name matches a row. If you get a match, increment the quantity. I think you have all the necessary knowledge to get this done judging by your code, you're just not taking the time to think through how the logic should work.

Comment: ok sir i will try but if it not work you have to help me please

Comment: I *am* helping you. If by "have to help you" you mean "just tell me the code" then I don't think you're going to learn very well that way. Give it a try, between the code you've posted and the hints I've given you, I think you can do this yourself if you just give it a proper try.

Comment: thank you for the motivation, i really want to learn and i will do it definitely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic implementation I would have expected you to be able to come up with.

```
protected void lnkBtnReadyToServeAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtCart = (DataTable)Session["sessiondtCart"];
    foreach(DataRow row in dtCart.Rows)
    {
        if(row["ProductName"] == lblProductName.Text) //check if already exists
        {
            //now we know we need to increment the quantity, because it's already in the cart
            int quantity = row["TotalPrice"] / int.Parse(lblProductPrice.Text);
            row["TotalPrice"] = quantity + int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            //now we know the item wasn't in the cart, so we need to add it
            dtCart.Rows.Add(lblProductName.Text, lblProductPrice.Text, txtQuantity.Text, imgk1.ImageUrl, int.Parse(lblProductPrice.Text) * int.Parse(txtQuantity.Text));
        }
    }

    Session["sessiondtCart"] = dtCart;
}
```

Quite a few notes here. You don't appear to be using an ID for your products, so instead we're forced to rely on the product name being unique. That's not very good, it's usually best to assign each product a unique ID.

You should not store prices in the cart. You should just store the ProductId and the Quantity. When you want to know the price, you should look up in the database what the price is. Otherwise, someone could easily manipulate `lblProductPrice` to be 0 and get the products for free. It would also simplify the logic for updating the quantity, as you'd no longer have to divide the total price to get the existing quantity.

And lastly, you're using ints for your prices. That might be fine for a quick demo. But what if your product price is $3.99? You should use a decimal or a double instead of an integer. Quantity is probably fine as an int, since most of the time you won't have fractional quantities.

Comment: yayyyyyy! i've solved that problem , thank u sir for your help